# Table doesn't exist in nested query with aggregations

Tags: mysql-error-1146

My database name is test, I have a table named HaveGoal.
I am querying this:

SELECT Rel.total
 
FROM (SELECT H.number, H.teamname, SUM(H.numberofgoals) AS total
 
FROM HaveGoal H GROUP BY H.number,H.teamname) AS Rel
 
WHERE Rel.total = (SELECT MAX(Rel.total) FROM Rel)

It gives:ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.Rel' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the last subselect cannot reference a nested query defined in the `FROM` clause.

In this case you have multiple solutions :

- Duplicate the first subselect inside the second (and hope that performance will not be too poor)
- Define a view to make the nested query available everywhere
- As you are looking for the maximum, you could sort data and take only the first line
- If you where not on MySQL, you could use the `WITH` statement

Duplicating will work in any situation :

```
SELECT Rel.total
FROM (
    SELECT H.number, H.teamname, SUM(H.numberofgoals) AS total
    FROM HaveGoal H 
    GROUP BY H.number,H.teamname
) AS Rel
WHERE Rel.total = (
    SELECT MAX(Rel2.total) 
    FROM (
        SELECT H.number, H.teamname, SUM(H.numberofgoals) AS total
        FROM HaveGoal H 
        GROUP BY H.number,H.teamname
    ) AS Rel2
)
```

Taking the first line after sorting is much shorter, but the `MAX` is implied :

```
SELECT Rel.total
FROM (
    SELECT H.number, H.teamname, SUM(H.numberofgoals) AS total
    FROM HaveGoalTest H 
    GROUP BY H.number,H.teamname
) AS Rel
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```